# Delete Trigger from Salesforce Production environment

Tags: salesforce

We have some inactive trigger in our salesforce production environment, As we are not using this, i want to delete those triggers, Any one know that how we can hard delete trigger from salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the Ant Migration Tool.  The same way a package.xml is used to define items you want to deploy, you create a destructiveChanges.xml file to delete components.

[Destructive Changes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/daas_destructive_changes.htm)

You put this xml file in the same folder as your package.xml and then do a normal deployment.  The package.xml can be empty if there are no new/updated files to deploy.